# Is submitting a page containing a lot of links to Google so it gets indexed considered bad?

Tags: seo, google, google-index

Each month, we're launching 200 websites (on 200 individual domains or subdomains) for a given brand (it means that those 200 websites have the same "look" and share some of the content (because it belongs to one brand)

Right now we're submitting 10 websites per day to Google Search Console (limit per account).

Can I submit a URL that contains the address of the 200 websites instead to save us from this manual time-consuming task?

- Is it considered harmful by Google?
- Will the 200 website on this page will be indexed as if we submitted them one by one?

Comment: Websites have long had "HTML sitemaps" which are just a page of links to make it easier for crawlers to get to all the content on the site.

Comment: Well the page won't contain link to the site itself (like a sitemap), it will contains the 200 links to the websites. For expample if I submit page `www.brand1.com`, it will contain `johndoe.brand1.com` `brand1-variant.com` `subdivision.brand1.com` ... so those website will be indexed without sending them 1 by 1 to Google

Comment: Submitting URLs to Google is far less effective than creating links on existing pages.

Comment: I'm also wondering what purpose you could have for so many sites, especially the brand variants.   It sounds like you may be trying to use them for a [link scheme](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356?hl=en) against Google's webmaster guidelines.   [Google's Matt Cutts also warns about too many sites](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0-jw_PfwtY) saying that 80 or 150 similar sites looks spammy.

Comment: Because each website is a brand-reseller website (with different location, and some different information) attached to the brand they are selling. But thx for the links

Comment: Submitting a site to (or rather, creating a property in) Google Search Console (GSC) is not necessarily "submitting the site to Google's index". It is simply "creating a property in GSC" - a natural by-product of this is that Google discovers your site (if it hasn't already). But you don't _need_ to do this to get discovered and indexed by Google.

Comment: @w3dk I'm not sure I follow you, will using GSC solve my problem ? Because you say using it will make Google discover the website. So If Google is aware, he'll index it right ?

Comment: Do not expect much if anything from Google by being so promiscuous in creating sites. You may be largely wasting time and effort.

Comment: Well, you seem to suggest that you need to create a property in GSC for your site in order to get indexed. What I'm saying is that you don't necessarily need to do that to get indexed. Google discovers sites through links and DNS and will naturally index content that it crawls (whether it appears in the SERPs is another matter). (The bigger problem would seem to be that you have "200 websites have the same 'look' and share some of the content" - regardless of whether they are submitted via GSC or discovered by organic means.)

Comment: If the product remains the same ultimately at some point some sites will not rank very well at all. This is due to the fact that you can only write about a product so many times before naturally some start to appear very similar. This becomes more of a problem if you have the same content writers, but even if your armed with a different content writer for each site, at some point... it will happen. This is why so many sites never rank well for products and use Google Adwords, because there are already many sites with similar pages which get priority due to post date and authority.

Answer (score 1):

Let me start off by saying that I agree with the comments that have already been posted.

Create a wordpress.com blog e.g. `brand.wordpress.com` (wordpress ranks well and is highly crawled and trusted by Google) and use that blog to share links to the sites.

If you want to be lazy, you can just create 1 single page/post with links to all the sites and yes, Google will crawl them all and probably index them all (kinda spammy/risky).

If you want to do it right and don't mind doing the work, use it as an actual blog. Every time you launch a new site, create a new post and link to it while adding some (unique) content about it (owner, location, etc.).

Simply posting the links on that blog is almost certainly enough to get them indexed by Google and other search engines.